# Is there a way to view or otherwise verify a contract's source code?

Tags: solidity, contract-verification

In token sales usually the source code for the contract is published. Is there a way to verify whether the published code is actually deployed in the given address?

Answer (score 1):

If the source code is published you can verify it with the deployed code the using tool like [Etherscan Verify Contract Code](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract).

You can only view the byte code or the opcode of a contract from a explorer like etherscan (See [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6d5cac36c1ae39f41d52393b7a425d0a610ad9f2#code)). If the source code is not published, due to the optimizations done by the compiler you can't get the source code back from opcode/bytecode.